# Can I disable the Google/YouTube notifications for people +1'ing comments?

Tags: youtube, google-plus, notifications

I voted for or replied to a comment on YouTube and now the Google bell icon thing won't leave me alone. (And it's everywhere!!)

- I don't want to know if someone else +1'ed a comment I replied to!
- I also don't want to know if someone replies to the comment I replied to.
- I would like to know when someone replies to ME.

**Is there any way to customize ANY comment/notification stuff from Google plus/YouTube?**

The whole 'comments moving from YT to G+' wasn't their best move IMO.

I found these, which are not useful:

- https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1054277
- https://plus.google.com/settings
- http://www.plusyourbusiness.com/guide-google-plus-notifications/ (a lot of detail that I can't find in G+ or YT)
- https://support.google.com/plus/answer/1687385?hl=en

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://plus.google.com/settings

Have you tried expanding the "posts", and uncheck those? That seems to do it for me.

Comment: I have, at some point, and I do think it works.

Comment: it's a shame they labeled it "emails", but they also works on youtube notifications. i have no idea why they are doing the whole G+ thing. sigh. glad it works.

Answer (score 1):

I went around and around with this, and finally--after many discussions with Google experts--finally got an actual Google staff person, who said you cannot stop these inane and intrusive red notifications; it took the staffer a very long time, meaning many backs and forths, to stop trying to tell me: WHY I was getting them, why I *should* get them, why I didn't understand the value of getting them, why everyone else wants them, what I would be missing without them, how it is part of the google product suite which was carefully redesigned and integrated, that it was not a gmail issues, nor a youtube issue, but a wonderful Google+ enhancement, why I was foolish, misguided, and apparently a bit thick (basically) if I still insisted I wanted to opt out--finally, while still evidently believing I was too stupid to "understand," capitulated: no, you cannot turn off these fricking notifications, no matter what. They are like kale chips and coconut oil: good for you. So eat them and shut up. That is the answer.